# Error al instalar php-db en Debian 10 Buster

Tags: php, linux, debian

Estoy intentando instalar PandoraFMS-Console en un VPS Debian 10 Buster. He instalado todas las dependencias necesarias excepto el paquete php-db que no soy capaz de instalar, y el cual es estríctamente necesario:

Cuando intento instalar el .deb de PandoraFMS-Console:

```
[...]
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of pandorafms-console:
  pandorafms-console depends on php-db; however:
    Package php-db is not installed.
```

Intento entonces instalar php-db pero me encuentro esto:

```
# apt install php-db
[...]
Package php-db is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'php-db' has no installation candidate
```

En packages.debian.org me encuentro lo siguiente, entiendo que no hay una versión del paquete php-db para la versión 10:

```
Package php-db

+ jessie (oldoldstable) (php): PHP PEAR Database Abstraction Layer
  1.7.14-3: all
+ stretch (oldstable) (php): Database Abstraction Layer
  1.9.2-1: all
+ sid (unstable) (php): Database Abstraction Layer
  1.9.2-2: all
```

Para más información, en /etc/apt/sources.list tengo lo siguiente (obviados comentarios):

```
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian buster main
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian buster main

deb http://security.debian.org/ buster/updates main
deb-src http://security.debian.org/ buster/updates main
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-updates main
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-updates main

deb http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-backports main
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-backports main
```

La carpeta /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ está vacía.

¿Qué puedo hacer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finalmente descargué el paquete manualmente de [aquí](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/php-db), Instalando previamente las dependencias necesarias (apt install php-common php-pear) y realizando la instalación manualmente:

```
dpkg -i php-db_1.9.2-1_all.deb
apt-mark hold php-db
```